# Do I need to maintain foreign keys at the database level when using Eloquent ORM?

Tags: database, orm, foreign-keys, laravel, eloquent

Eloquent can effectively manage all relationships with Eloquent Models. So, do I really need to maintain foreign key relationships in the database? Does maintaining relationships at the database level have any additional effect on the performance of the application, since the data integrity is already being managed by the ORM layer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally don't like to keep foreign key relationships in the database when using Eloquent as I want to handle all the dependency logic in one place (the app layer).

There's really no reasons performance-wise to have foreign keys, it is purely a architectural/design decision.